# Returning a Parameter from a Python Tkinter Pop-Up-Window Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, popupwindow, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a pop up window with Tkinter where I can enter values with an entry window to use them in the main code.

Currently I am trying to simply output the input. I can't get it to work, does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?
Here is a small snippet of my code. I have not used the variables from the functions anywhere else in the code.

```
root = Tk()  # set up GUI
menuleiste = Menu(root) #menu bar


def take_over_Temp():
    #Tempstring = str(eKnopf.get())
    print(eKnopf.get())
    print("got it")


def open_popup():
   #global eKnopf
   top= Toplevel(root)
   top.geometry("750x250")
   top.title("Child Window")
   #Label(top, text= "Hello World!", font=('Mistral 18 bold')).place(x=150,y=80)
   eKnopf = Entry(top, bd = 5).place(x=10,y=100, width=100)
   button_take_Temp = Button(top, text='Set Temperature', fg="red", command=take_over_Temp)
   button_take_Temp.place(x=10, y=150, width=100)
   return(eKnopf)


optionen_menu.add_command(label="Offset", command = open_popup)
```

When I try it like this I get this Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/user/FAC.py", line 724, in take_over_Temp
    print(eKnopf.get())
NameError: name 'eKnopf' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in `eKnopf` as a parameter to `take_over_Temp()`

```
eKnopf = Entry(top, bd = 5)
eKnopf.place(x=10, y=100, width=100)
button_take_Temp = Button(
    top,
    text='Set Temperature', 
    fg="red", 
    # use a lambda to pass `eKnopf` as an argument 
    command=lambda ent=eKnopf: take_over_Temp(ent)
)
```

Then modify `take_over_Temp` to accept and use that value:

```
def take_over_Temp(ent):
    print(ent.get())
```

FYI, the error you're seeing is essentially saying that the function `take_over_Temp` doesn't know what `eKnopf` is because it doesn't exist within the scope of the function.

Comment: Okay, I have tried that but now I'm getting this Error:


```

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/user/ForcedAirCooling_ver5_2_HWautodetect.py", line 738, in <lambda>
    command=lambda ent=eKnopf: take_over_Temp(ent)
  File "/home/user/ForcedAirCooling_ver5_2_HWautodetect.py", line 724, in take_over_Temp
    print(ent.get())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'


```

Comment: I've updated the answer - should fix the problem! The trouble was caused by declaring the `Entry` and immediately calling `place()` on it. Since `place()` returns `None`, `eKnopf` was evaluating to `None` instead of an instance of `Entry`.  Pro tip: always declare your widgets on one line and then `pack`/`place`/`grid` them on a separate line for this reason! Sorry I missed that.